# php mysql query and array association

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have the next databases:

```
+------+---------------+-------+
|  Id  |     Title     | Price |
+------+---------------+-------+
|  300 | Part1         |    30 |
|  400 | Part2         |    40 |
|  500 | Part3         |    50 |
| 3215 | Promo Package |   130 |
+------+---------------+-------+
```

And

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| Promo_prod_main | product_part |
+-----------------+--------------+
|            3215 |          300 |
|            3215 |          400 |
|            3215 |          500 |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

Those two would create lets say a promo package(the 3 products).

The problem is that sometimes , the prices on the 3 parts change but it won't affect the promo package price.

I decided to create a script that selects each promo package and then gets the products that its created from , sum up the array of the prices and then update the promo package.

All good thinking until I got to code , I managed this far:

```
$rezultatebumb = mysqli_query($linkul, "SELECT id,title,price FROM product WHERE attr_group_id IS NULL AND is_homepage IS NULL") or die(mysqli_error($linkul)); // this query only selects the promo packages
$array_m = array();
foreach ($rezultatebumb as $valc) {
    $array_m[] = $valc['id'];
}

$array_s = array();
foreach ($array_m as $arr) {
    $rezprod = mysqli_query($linkul, "SELECT product_part FROM product_promo WHERE Promo_prod_main=" . $arr) or die(mysqli_error($linkul));
    $tesat = $rezprod->fetch_assoc();

    $array_s[] = $tesat['product_part'];
    echo count($array_s);

}

print_r($array_s);
echo '</br></br>';
print_r($array_m);
```

**results next->**

**One product from each package**

```
Array ( [0] => 146 [1] => 1497 [2] => 565 [3] => 6576 [4] => 1516 )
```

**Each promo package**

```
Array ( [0] => 5732 [1] => 5758 [2] => 6998 [3] => 7032 [4] => 7033 )
```

Before I get messages like 'You're supposed to write the code yourself' , well I tried, I just can't get anywhere past this point.

I will appreciate any tip or fix to this problem , thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the only thing I understand is this part.

> I decided to create a script that selects each promo package and then
>   gets the products that its created from , sum up the array of the
>   prices and then update the promo package.

So, You can something like joins to get an array of all products which are associated with the promo package.

```
SELECT p.Price from product p
join promo_table pt 
on (p.Id = pt.Promo_prod_main)
where pt.promo_prod_main=3215
```

Pass it results on array and then do **array_sum()** to array to get the total of price.

And then update it's total price

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join to have the package prepared. With query of inner join:

```
select * from package a 
inner join product b
on a.package_id = b.package_id
where a.package_id = 5
```

Something on these lines, you should have pacakage_id corresponding to each product. Or you can have another mapping table to map a product with various packages.